# Return top 3 rows per group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

When I made this select it shows as result all “rut” with it phone numbers, my problem
  is that each “rut” has almost 10 phone numbers, and I need just 3 phone numbers for
  each “rut”, I tryied using TOP, but just shows the first 3 rows of all table and not the
  first rows by “rut”, how can I use TOP just  for the row “rut” and not in the all the
  table

```
Select Distinct  
t1.rut_cliente as rut_cliente,
t1.nro_fono  as numero 
--Into #tmp_numeros
From dat_clientes_sucursales_contactos_telefonos t1,dat_rut_clientes t2
where  t1.rut_cliente = t2.rut_cliente 
and cod_prioridad = 1
```

this is what I get with this query:

```
  Rut_cliente   Nro_fono 
  60506000-5    2046840
  60506000-5    3507935
  60506000-5    4106886
  60506000-5    5440000
  60506000-5    5445000
  81698900-0    2373281
  81698900-0    3541342
  81698900-0    3541438
  81698900-0    3541518
  81698900-0    3542101
```

and this is what I want:

```
  Rut_cliente   Nro_fono 
  60506000-5    2046840
  60506000-5    3507935
  60506000-5    4106886
  81698900-0    2373281
  81698900-0    3541342
  81698900-0    3541438
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The question was originally tagged SQL Server 2008, where you can do this using a common table expression:

```
;WITH x AS 
 (
   SELECT Rut_cliente, Nro_fono, rn = ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER (PARTITION BY Rut_cliente ORDER BY Nro_fono)
   FROM dbo.dat_clientes_sucursales_contactos_telefonos AS t1
   INNER JOIN dbo.dat_rut_clientes AS t2
   ON t1.rut_cliente = t2.rut_cliente
   WHERE cod_prioridad = 1
)
SELECT Rut_cliente, Nro_fono FROM x
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY Rut_cliente, Nro_fono;
```

Other comments:

- Please don't use `table, table` syntax. Use proper `INNER JOIN`s. I [explain why here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).
- Please add proper aliases to the inner query, so people know which columns come from t1 and which columns come from t2.

---

But now we learn the user is actually using SQL Server 2000. This is how I would do it there, I think, but performance is going to be horrible. I'm not 100% sure this works (because again I'm making guesses about which columns come from which table).

```
SELECT x.rut_cliente, x.nro_fono, COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.rut_cliente, t1.nro_fono
    FROM dat_clientes_sucursales_contactos_telefonos AS t1
    INNER JOIN dat_rut_clientes AS t2
    ON t1.rut_cliente = t2.rut_cliente
    WHERE cod_prioridad = 1
) AS x
INNER JOIN dat_clientes_sucursales_contactos_telefonos AS b
ON b.rut_cliente = x.rut_cliente
AND b.nro_fono <= x.nro_fono
GROUP BY x.rut_cliente, x.nro_fono
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY x.rut_cliente, x.Nro_fono;
```

Comment: @Tim thanks, let's just be careful not to look like a voting ring. :-)

Answer (score 5):

For example with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) which is a window function and returns a row-number for each partition(similar to `group by`) determined by the `order by`.:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT t1.rut_cliente as rut_cliente, t1.nro_fono  as numero,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Rut_cliente ORDER BY Nro_fono)
   FROM dbo.dat_clientes_sucursales_contactos_telefonos AS t1
   INNER JOIN dbo.dat_rut_clientes AS t2 ON t1.rut_cliente = t2.rut_cliente
   WHERE cod_prioridad = 1
)
SELECT rut_cliente as rut_cliente, nro_fono  as numero
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 3
```

Comment: +1 both because you re-wrote the join and because I only beat you by 12 seconds. :-)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter
 when I use your code I get this: 'ROW_NUMBER'is not a name of a function

Comment: @suely your post says you are using SQL Server 2008. Are you sure? Perhaps that is the version of Management Studio you are using, but you are connecting to SQL Server 2000? What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` yield?

Comment: Then you should edit your question to show the complete query that you've tried. Maybe you've omitted the `OVER(PARTITION...`.

Comment: @suely: I assume Aaron is your man, i "_grew up_" with sql-server 2005.

Comment: Yeah I've forgotten more SQL Server 2000 crap than I'd like to admit, and it is quite painful to simulate newer functionality there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with CTE AS (
select Rut_cliente, Nro_fono , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY Rut_cliente ORDER BY Nro_fono) rn
 FROM dbo.dat_clientes_sucursales_contactos_telefonos AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.dat_rut_clientes AS b
ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_cliente
WHERE cod_prioridad = 1

)
SELECT * FROM CTE where rn <=3
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out,fixed now. this was a sample query for user to use, user can replace @table with table names and joins